# How can I install a gem from a Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

From a Ruby script, I want to send a command to install a gem if it is missing. Let's say it is `"foo"`. I thought that the command to check the existence of a gem were `Gem.find_files` and the command to install a gem were `Gem.install`. I tried this:

```
if Gem.find_files("foo").empty?
  Gem.install("foo")
end
```

and `Gem.find_files` seems to work, but `Gem.install` returns an error `Uninitialized constant Gem::DependencyInstaller`. Assuming that this is the first part of the code to be run, and I am working with a freshly installed Ruby with no gems installed at this point other than the core libraries that come with Ruby 2, what is the correct way to install the gems from Ruby script (not from the shell)?

Comment: why don't you use bundler and bundle install?

Comment: It's really unusual for Ruby applications to install dependencies themselves, especially without asking first.

Comment: @SamD I thought that someone might say something like that. You can't use bundler unless you have installed bundler.

Comment: @tadman I can add the asking part and user prompt for whether to continue. Actually, there are more things like that in my code. I omitted that here for simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
require 'rubygems/dependency_installer.rb'
```

?